# how to get in extjs getHours() values in 12 hours format currently getting hour values in 24 hours format

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        var t1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Time', {
            xtype: 'timefield',
            name: 'in',
            fieldLabel: 'Time In',
            minValue: '6:00 AM',
            maxValue: '8:00 PM',
            increment: 60,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        var time = Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.HOUR, + 14).getHours(); //getting hour values in 24 format want in 12 hours format
        t1.setMaxValue(time); //unable to setMaxValue
    }
});
```

Comment: This is your eleventh question, others had to reformat your code in each and every of them, and you show no interest in changing that...

Comment: What version of ExtJs is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [Ext.Date](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Date.html) class for getting 12 hours format.

Here is defied some formats:-

1. **g** 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 1 to 12
2. **i** Minutes, with leading zeros 00 to 59
3. **a** Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem am or pm
4. **A** Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem AM or PM

I have created an [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/285l) demo it is showing how is working. Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Time Card',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        minValue: '6:00 AM',
        maxValue: '8:00 PM',
        increment: 30,
        anchor: '100%',
        listeners: {
            change: function (timefield, newValue) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Succes', 'Good you have selected <b>' + Ext.Date.format(newValue, 'g:i A') + '</b>');
            }
        }
    },
    items: [{
        name: 'in',
        fieldLabel: 'Time In'
    }, {
        name: 'out',
        fieldLabel: 'Time Out'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Get current GMT+14 Time',
        handler: function () {
            var date = new Date(),
                dateGmtPlus14 = new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); //Multiply this by 60,000 (milliseconds in a minute) to get the milliseconds and subtract from the date to create a new date

            Ext.Msg.alert('Succes', 'Current time with GMT+14 is <br> 12 hours format : <b>' + Ext.Date.format(dateGmtPlus14, 'g:i:s A') +
                '</b><br>24 hours format: <b> ' + Ext.Date.format(dateGmtPlus14, 'G:i:s') + '</b>');
        }
    }]
});
```

You can use [Date.getTimezoneOffset()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). This returns the time difference between your date and GMT in minutes.

Multiply this by 60,000 (milliseconds in a minute) to get the milliseconds and subtract from the date to create a new date.

```
new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

Comment: is there anyway to get current GMT+14 time in extjs to pass to time fields

Comment: means do you want next 14 hours time from current time ?

Comment: no i need to get current GMT+14 time https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/gmt-plus-14/ in this link to pass to my time fields

Comment: Please see I have updated my answer as per [GMT+14](https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/gmt-plus-14/) here on same [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/285l)